# Creating view with calculated columns

Tags: sql-server

Okay guys,

So i have a table with various columns and around 40 records, what i need to do is create a view that only displays 3 of the columns, and then calculates a new column based on results from the other columns.

The columns are as follows, JobID, SDate & FDate (Start Date and FinishDate), What i need is a new column called grades within this view that if start date and finish date are the same then 'A+', If it took more than one day then 'A', If more than two days then 'B', Else 'C'.

What would be the best approach to this, I'm quite new to SQL and my experience is somewhat limited.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio R2.
And yes it must be a view as this was the task given to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, here's how you create a view: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx  And here's how you include a conditional (a `CASE` statement) in your `SELECT`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx  Both found very easily via Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use [`CASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT JobID, SDate, FDate, CASE WHEN SDate = FDate THEN 'A+' WHEN DATEADD(d, 1, SDate) = FDate THEN 'A' WHEN DATEADD(d, 2, SDate) = FDate THEN 'B' ELSE 'C' END AS Grades
FROM ...
```